# How to iterate ngcontainer tag in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to create a table using angular material, code given below is working fine so far, but it seems duplicating 'ng-container' for each columns. Is there any way to iterate through this in Typescript?

**HTML**

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
```

```
<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name" sticky>
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Position Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Weight Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in typescript. You can convert to angular using NgFor keyPair pipe.

```
let element = {
  name: 'test 1',
  position: 0,
  weight: 500
};

for(let itemkey in element){

  console.log(elem);

  <ng-container matColumnDef="{{itemkey}}" sticky>
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{itemkey.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}} </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[itemkey]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

}
```